# Tor command line to detect remote ip

Tags: telnet, tor

is there a command to detect the actual ip that is using tor when connected to tor via telnet?

I mean like sending "getinfo circuit-status" or "signal newnym" commands

Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific about the senario.  Are you trying to detect real IPs as a exit node, hidden service, bridge etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"getinfo address" will tell you what tor believes your current external IP address to be. It sounds like you might be interested in what the final hop of an arbitrary circuit is. You can figure this out from your "getinfo circuit-status" query by looking up the IP of the last router in the path.

So, if one of the circuits lists its path as `$000000000000000000000000000,$111111111111111111111111111,$222222222222222222222222222` then you may issue another query "`getinfo ns/id/222222222222222222222222222`" to determine the IP of that last router.

Answer (score 0):

This is the second question I've seen about [getting the IP of your present exit relays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777192/how-do-i-get-the-tor-exit-node-ip-address-over-the-control-port). It's an interesting question so I've added a [FAQ entry for it](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-get-information-about-my-exits) - hope this helps!