# How to get the Tor ExitNode IP with Python and Stem

Tags: ip, tor, stem

I'm trying to get the external IP that Tor uses, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777192/how-do-i-get-the-tor-exit-node-ip-address-over-the-control-port). When using something like myip.dnsomatic.com, this is very slow. I tried what was suggested in the aforementioned link (python + stem to control tor through the control port), but all you get is circuit's IPs with no assurance of which one is the one on the exitnode, and, sometimes the real IP is not even among the results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096379/tor-with-python), at the bottom, Amine suggests a way to renew the identity in Tor. There is an instruction, **controller.get_newnym_wait()**, which he uses to wait until the new connection is ready (controller is from Control in steam.control), isn't there any thing like that in Steam (sorry, I checked and double/triple checked and couldn't find nothing) that tells you that Tor is changing its identity?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the exit node ip without calling a geoip site.

This is however on a different stackexchange site here - https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/how-do-i-trap-circuit-id-none-errors-in-the-stem-script-exit-used-py

As posted by @mirimir his code below essentially attaches a stream event listener function, which is then used to get the circuit id, circuit fingerprint, then finally the exit ip address -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import functools
import time
from stem import StreamStatus
from stem.control import EventType, Controller

def main():
  print "Tracking requests for tor exits. Press 'enter' to end."
  print

  with Controller.from_port() as controller:
    controller.authenticate()

    stream_listener = functools.partial(stream_event, controller)
    controller.add_event_listener(stream_listener, EventType.STREAM)

    raw_input()  # wait for user to press enter

def stream_event(controller, event):
  if event.status == StreamStatus.SUCCEEDED and event.circ_id:
    circ = controller.get_circuit(event.circ_id)
    exit_fingerprint = circ.path[-1][0]
    exit_relay = controller.get_network_status(exit_fingerprint)
    t = time.localtime()

    print "datetime|%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d % (t.tm_year, t.tm_mon, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec)
    print "website|%s" % (event.target)
    print "exitip|%s" % (exit_relay.address)
    print "exitport|%i" % (exit_relay.or_port)
    print "fingerprint|%s" % exit_relay.fingerprint
    print "nickname|%s" % exit_relay.nickname
    print "locale|%s" % controller.get_info("ip-to-country/%s" % exit_relay.address, 'unknown')
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for check current IP (change SOCKS_PORT value to yours):

```
import re

import stem.process
import requesocks

SOCKS_PORT = 9053

tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor()
proxy_address = 'socks5://127.0.0.1:{}'.format(SOCKS_PORT)
proxies = {
            'http': proxy_address,
            'https': proxy_address
        }
response = requesocks.get("http://httpbin.org/ip", proxies=proxies)
print re.findall(r'[\d.-]+', response.text)[0]
tor_process.kill()
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. Even without calling Signal for a new circuit - Multiple calls to the socks5 proxy port will change the ip. So calling a geoip site before calling your real url wont work.

Comment: @EDENDEKKER If I correctly understood your problem, you need  to look in this direction https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/4807

Comment: @ELRUSSO You are right. That makes sense. You probably saved lots of people hours of wondering why it keeps changing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use socks you should do:

```
pip install requests[socks]
```

Then you can do:

```
import requests
import json
import stem.process
import stem


SOCKS_PORT = "9999"

tor = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    config={
        'SocksPort': SOCKS_PORT,
    },
    tor_cmd= 'absolute_path/to/tor.exe',
)

r = requests.Session()

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://localhost:' + SOCKS_PORT,
    'https': 'socks5://localhost:' + SOCKS_PORT
}

response = r.get("http://httpbin.org/ip", proxies=proxies)
self.current_ip = response.json()['origin']
```