# How do I get the *current* Tor exit node IP address over the control port?

Tags: ip, tor, stem

How do I get the external IP address of the **current** Tor exit node (the one which is in use) **without** using external services/websites (through `curl` or otherwise) but only through the Tor control port functionality (using bash or python3).

NOTE: I have been looking for an answer to this question and found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777192/how-do-i-get-the-tor-exit-node-ip-address-over-the-control-port) (which lists all exit nodes) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448750/how-to-get-the-tor-exitnode-ip-with-python-and-stem) (which does *not* give the IP address of the current exit node but of some other node). Other answers suggest using external services through `curl` or otherwise which is not what I am looking for.

I am using GNU/Linux.

Comment: Some suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50863271/892493

Answer (score 1):

cid - is circuit id with currently in use or any other circuit id you want.
1 - by cid we retrieve circuit event whith circuit state , we taking finger print of exit node(last element in path property).
2 - checking network status and take address property.

```
er = controller.get_circuit(cid).path[-1][0]
ip = controller.get_network_status(er).address
```

or I not try it yet, there is

```
get_network_statuses - provides all presently available router status entries
```

hope it helps. 
https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html